# CSP frame-ancestors - How to block the entire domain except one page?

Tags: php, html, iframe, content-security-policy

I have a website and I want to allow it to be displayed within an Iframe on another domain.
I am using a PHP header to allow this. However, I just want my site to run on a specific page, rather than the entire domain.

I have this code: `header ("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://example.com/");`

I just want to allow a specific URL (ex: https://example.com/example.php), but actually the entire domain can show my site within an Iframe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the Content Security Policy allows to use `path-part` and even `filename` in the directives. The rule `script-src example.com/js/script.js` will allow to load specified script only.

But `frame-ancestors` directive is special. Firefox supports [using paths](https://csplite.com/csp/test355/) in the sources, but Chrome browser - does not.

Most likely, this behavior of Chrome is due to the fact that frame-ancestors regulates the embedding of your resource on third-party resources. Using paths and file names in this directive will restrict the owner of a third-party resource from changing the Url structure without your agreement. Which, in general, is very inconvenient.

Comment: So, what would you recommend me if I just wanted to display my website on a specific page? I also tried to get the top page URL via JavaScript, but it is impossible due to cross-domain security.

Comment: You can disable embedding by default via `frame-ancestors 'none'` and check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - if it's match allowed Urls then do not publish `frame-ancestor`. You can offer third party to use your own javascript to inject iframe like it do Google Adsense for Ads or Disqus.com/Commento.io comments widgets. For Adsense you can blacklist some domains. The above comments widgets show comments thread for specific Urls. So your task is solvable in general, but not with CSP.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']